# How this series summation is produced?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

For a positive integer $n$ let's define a function $f$:

$$f(n) =  - 1 + 2 - 3 + .. + ( - 1)^nn$$ where $1 ≤ n ≤ 10^{15}$.

The solution for this series is:

- If $n$ is even, then the answer is $n / 2$.
- If $n$ is odd the answer is $(n - 1) / 2 - n$ that means  $- (n + 1) / 2$.

But how ? I need some explanation for better understanding.

Comment: Just so you know, you can write math syntax when you are inside dollar sign \$ \$ pairs, just as you can write code syntax when you are inside those tic \` \` pairs.

Comment: Let $S(n)$ denote the sum of first $n$-natural numbers. Then can you say what is $S(2n)-f(2n)$? What is $S(2n+1)-f(2n+1)$? Can you express both of them as functions of $n$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}f(2n)&=-1+2-3+\dots-(2n-1)+(2n)\\&=(-1+2)+(-3+4)+\dots+[-(2n-1)-(2n)]\\&=1+1+\dots+1\\&=n\end{align}$$

$$f(2n+1)=f(2n)-(2n+1)=-(n+1)$$

Now let $2n\to n$ for the even cases and $2n+1\to n$ for the odd cases.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}S&=r+r^2+r^3+\dots+r^n\\-\left(rS\right.&=\left.\quad\ \ \ r^2+r^3+\dots+r^n+r^{n+1}\right)\\\hline(1-r)S&=r+0\phantom{^2}+0\phantom{^2}+\ldots+0\phantom{^n}-r^{n+1}\end{align}\\(1-r)S=r-r^{n+1}\\S=\frac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

---

Calculus proof:

Begin with power rule on the left, quotient rule on the right.

$$\begin{align}\frac d{dr}r+r^2+r^3+\dots+r^n&=\frac d{dr}\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\\1+2r+3r^2+\dots+nr^{n-1}&=\frac{nr^{n+1}-(n+1)r^n+1}{(1-r)^2}\end{align}$$

Multiply both sides by $r$.

> $$r+2r^2+3r^3+\dots+nr^n=\frac{r\left(nr^{n+1}-(n+1)r^n+1\right)}{(1-r)^2}$$

---

Algebraic proof:

$$\begin{align}T&=r+2r^2+3r^3+\dots+\qquad\ \ nr^n\\-\left(rT\right.&=\left.\phantom{r+2}r^2+2r^3+\dots+(n-1)r^n+nr^{n+1}\right)\\\hline(1-r)T&=r+\phantom2r^2+\phantom2r^3+\ldots+\phantom{(n-1)} r^n-nr^{n+1}\end{align}\\(1-r)T=S-nr^{n+1}\\T=\frac{S-nr^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

> $$T=\frac{r(nr^{n+1}-(n+1)r^n+1)}{(1-r)^2}$$
>
> $$r+2r^2+3r^3+\dots+nr^n=\frac{r(nr^{n+1}-(n+1)r^n+1)}{(1-r)^2}$$

---

For $r=-1$, we have

$$\begin{align}-1+2-3+\dots+n(-1)^n&=\frac{-(n(-1)^{n+1}-(n+1)(-1)^n+1)}{(1-(-1))^2}\\&=\frac{n(-1)^n+(n+1)(-1)^n-1}4\\&=\frac{(2n+1)(-1)^n-1}4\end{align}$$

Consider $(-1)^n$ for even and odd cases.

Comment: I think that one can obtain more simply the expression for $r+2r^2+\ldots+nr^n$ by differentiating $1+r+r^2+\ldots+r^{n}$ with respect to $r$ and then multiplying the result by $r$.

Comment: @user170039 If you check the first revision to my answer, that is what I originally had.  But then I thought the OP would more likely understand the algebraic derivation, and it's not like it took that many more lines.

Comment: Sure. But I think in that case you could separate your answer in two parts, one elaborating that method using differentiation and the other as you have written.

Comment: @user170039 Does that satisfy you?

Comment: My satisfaction is immaterial here. I was simply telling you what in my opinion would be a more complete answer. It's upto you whether you should accept my suggestion or not.

Answer (score 0):

First separate positive terms and negative terms.solve them individually.Then add both.You will get the answer

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the amount of positive and negative terms vary.  Also, solving for the positive or negative sums is a problem in and of itself.